# Time-based averaging (sliding window) of columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame which has multiple columns. One of the columns is time and is thus non-decreasing. Rest of the columns contain observations recorded at the time given by the time specified in a certain row of the data.frame.

I want to select a window of time, say "x" seconds, and calculate the average (or for that matter any function) of the entries in some other columns in the same data.frame for that window.

Of course, because its a time based average, the number of entries in a window can vary depending upon the data. This is because the number of rows belonging to a certain time window can vary.

I have done this using a custom function, which creates a new column in the data.frame. The new column assigns a single number to all the entries in a time window. The number is unique across all the time windows. This essentially divides the data into groups based on the time windows. Then I use R's "aggregate" function to do calculate the mean.

I was just wondering if there is an existing R function that can do the grouping based on a time interval or if there is a better (cleaner) way to do this.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data?  The best solution is going to depend on what your data look like.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible, because i do it by my self but it is very CPU consumming so i don't know maybe i have to set the windows to a more large value, anyway TY ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` contains only numeric data, this is one way to do it using zoo/xts:

```
> Data <- data.frame(Time=Sys.time()+1:20,x=rnorm(20))
> xData <- xts(Data[,-1], Data[,1])
> period.apply(xData, endpoints(xData, "seconds", 5), colMeans)
                           [,1]
2010-10-20 13:34:19 -0.20725660
2010-10-20 13:34:24 -0.01219346
2010-10-20 13:34:29 -0.70717312
2010-10-20 13:34:34  0.09338097
2010-10-20 13:34:38 -0.22330363
```

EDIT: using only base R packages.  The means are the same, but the times are slightly different because `endpoints` starts the 5-second interval with the first observation.  The code below groups on 5-second intervals starting with seconds = 0.

```
> nSeconds <- 5
> agg <- aggregate(Data[,-1], by=list(as.numeric(Data$Time) %/% nSeconds), mean)
> agg[,1] <- .POSIXct(agg[,1]*nSeconds)  # >= R-2.12.0 required for .POSIXct
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is correct but I am still interested in how others would solve it using R

Comment: But this _is_ using R... or are you looking for a solution that only uses base R packages?

Comment: yes something the uses base R or atleast preserves the data.frame type, although I checked that I can use as.data.frame on the xts to convert it back, the only thing is I would have to explicitly add another column using row.names (time information) in order to create graphs with ggplot2

Comment: Neat solution - but the OP was asking about a sliding time window, whereas this chunks the data into discrete segments.  Is there a sliding-window analog of this?

Comment: @Ken: you could use `rollapply` for a sliding window but the window is based on the number of observations, not a specific time interval.  That may be problematic for irregular time series.

Comment: Thanks Joshua - I think I smell a new implementation of a time-based rolling window using loops. =)

Answer (score 1):

zoo has a `rollapply()` method. If you can't use it, I have rolled my own a few times. It isn't very difficult.