# Time Window as row of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a vector with dates and I want to assign a certain Time Window to each date. 
The dates of the Time Window should be in the rows of a data.frame. In my example, the Time Window contains the 5 days just before the reference/event date.

my vector:

```
days <- c("01.01.2000", "02.01.2000", "05.01.2000", "06.01.2000", "07.01.2000", "08.01.2000", "09.01.2000", "12.01.2000", "13.01.2000", "14.01.2000", "15.01.2000")
```

the output should look like this (the rows before 07.01.2000 don't really matter. Only data after the 07.01.2000 will be used):

```
#       days           1           2           3           4           5
# 01.01.2000
# 02.01.2000
# 05.01.2000
# 06.01.2000
# 07.01.2000 
# 08.01.2000  01.01.2000  02.01.2000  05.01.2000  06.01.2000  07.01.2000
# 09.01.2000  02.01.2000  05.01.2000  06.01.2000  07.01.2000  08.01.2000  
# 12.01.2000  05.01.2000  06.01.2000  07.01.2000  08.01.2000  09.01.2000
# 13.01.2000  06.01.2000  07.01.2000  08.01.2000  09.01.2000  12.01.2000
# 14.01.2000  07.01.2000  08.01.2000  09.01.2000  12.01.2000  13.01.2000
# 15.01.2000  08.01.2000  09.01.2000  12.01.2000  13.01.2000  14.01.2000
```

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Input is `15.01.2000`?

(2) It would be nicer to only output the rows between input-5days and input?

Comment: Why do you want this? This data format doesn't look useful at all and there is probably a better way to achieve your final goal.

Comment: anyhow, check out the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980814/time-based-averaging-sliding-window-of-columns-in-a-data-frame?rq=1 .

Comment: @ Roland: yeah you're probably right! I posted the "whole question" before, but didn't get any answers. That's why i'm posting only a crucial part of the task. It's just very hard/impossible to explain the whole task on a website like this. But I'm sure there's a much easier way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)

z <- lag(zoo(days), -c(0, 5:1))
coredata(z)
```

The last line can be omitted if you want the result as a zoo object.